# Mongodb Docker replica set communication issue with backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, docker-compose

I am using a docker to create a one node replica set of mongodb instance, so i can use transaction, session in mongodb as it is only supported in replicaset. But after setup(without auth) I am having issue as i can connect from my machine to the database but the backend can't connect. Though they are in same network. Might be missing something.

my docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3.9'

# inside services it has to be all the services here i have only two backend and database

services:

  backend:

    build:

      context: .

      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    container_name: node-api

    restart: always

    environment:

      - Mongoose_connect=mongodb://mongo-db:27017/niam?replicaSet=rs0




    volumes:

      - .:/app

    ports:

      - "4000:4000"

    depends_on:

      - database

    networks:

      - mern-network




  database:

    image: mongo:latest

    container_name: mongo-db

    restart: always

    command:

      [

        "--replSet",

        "rs0",

        "--bind_ip_all",

        "--port",

        "27017"

      ]

    ports:

      - 27017:27017

    extra_hosts:

      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

    healthcheck:

      test: echo "try { rs.status() } catch (err) { rs.initiate({_id:'rs0',members:[{_id:0,host:'host.docker.internal:27017'}]}) }" | mongosh --port 27017 --quiet

      interval: 5s

      timeout: 30s

      start_period: 0s

      start_interval: 1s

      retries: 30

    volumes:

      - "mongo1_data:/data/db"

      - "mongo1_config:/data/configdb"

    networks:

      - mern-network

volumes:

  mongo1_data:

  mongo1_config:




networks:

  mern-network:

    driver: bridge
```

But my backend can't get connected to the database,

But with mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0
I can connect with the database in my compass. But backend shows this error:

```
Connection String mongodb://mongo-db:27017/?replicaSet=rs0
Listening to PORT 4000
/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:805
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

What mistake i am making can you point it out?

Comment: Why do you create a config file `/data/configdb` when you don' use it? Why do you create a replica set with only one member? It does not make much sense. Instead of `echo '...' | mongosh --port 27017 --quiet` I suggest `mongosh --port 27017 --quiet --eval '...'` - usually this works better. After `rs.initiate()` I recommend command `while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) { sleep(1000) }` otherwise the shell may terminate before the replia set has been initialized fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can find below a working MongoDB replica-set (with 2 replicas) in docker-compose. There are some important comments in the compose file, please pay attention.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:4.4.5
    hostname: mongo1
    networks:
      - mongo_net
    # The following variables won't be used due to set entrypoint section
    # The replica-set sets automatically, but the admin user has to be set
    # only one time when you use new deploy.
    # I guess it can be automated, but I didn't have time for it...
    # Eg.:
    #    docker exec -it <docker-container-id> mongo
    #    use admin
    #    db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "admin_pwd", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] })
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test_db
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin_pwd
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
      - mongo-1:/data/db
      - ./docker-entrypoint-mongo.sh:/data/docker-entrypoint.sh
    # Probably the expose is not needed because the services can
    # communicate via any port inside Docker Network.
    expose:
      - 27017
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        chmod +x /data/docker-entrypoint.sh
        exec /data/docker-entrypoint.sh
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id:'my-replica-set',members:[{_id:0,host:\"mongo1:27017\"},{_id:1,host:\"mongo2:27017\"}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo --quiet ) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:4.4.5
    hostname: mongo2
    networks:
      - mongo_net
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test_db
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin_pwd
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
      - mongo-2:/data/db
      - ./docker-entrypoint-mongo.sh:/data/docker-entrypoint.sh
    expose:
      - 27017
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        chmod +x /data/docker-entrypoint.sh
        exec /data/docker-entrypoint.sh

volumes:
  mongo-1:
  mongo-2:

networks:
  mongo_net: {}
```

**docker-entrypoint-mongo.sh:**

```
mongod "--enableMajorityReadConcern" "false" "--journal" "--dbpath" "/data/db" "--replSet" "my-replica-set" "--bind_ip_all"
```

The connection string for MongoDB replica-set:

```
mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017/?replicaSet=my-replica-set
```

I am using it from a Python application and the DB engine is the following:

```
self.__mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    host=["mongo1:27017", "mongo2:27017"],
    username="admin",
    password="admin_pwd",
    replicaset="my-replica-set",
)
```